# How do I paint child in renderbox derivative?

Tags: flutter

I want to paint Widget in a RenderBox derivative. I tried the obvious, but no painting occured. What am I doing wrong?

Ive got a vague feeling that I should subclass RenderObjectWidget and do some sort of a Element, but I'd rather shortcut that

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const K());
}

class K extends LeafRenderObjectWidget {
  const K({super.key});

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {

    const w = SizedBox.square(
      dimension: 30,child: ColoredBox(color: Colors.green),
    );
    final row = w.createRenderObject(context);
    row.layout(const BoxConstraints());

    return KImpl(row);
  }
}

class KImpl extends RenderBox {

  KImpl(this.ro);

  RenderObject ro ;

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    final c = constraints.normalize();
    size = Size(c.maxWidth, c.maxHeight);
  }
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    context.canvas.drawColor(Colors.red, BlendMode.src);

    context.paintChild(ro, Offset.zero); // THIS HAS NO EFFECT !
  }
}
```

Comment: If your suggestion is to wrap `ro` into a `RenderProxyBox`, then it didn't work 

Comment: Also, I want to draw more then one Widget there